# How to use the memento design pattern to save the state of multiple objects?

Tags: design-patterns, memento

I'm very confused about how the memento is supposed to be implemented.

I understand the **Memento** has a **State**. And the **Memento Pattern** is used to store different (previous) **states** so that one can restore an **object** to previous **states**,

Well lets say I have multiple **objects**, each of this comes with 10 attributes, 5 of which stay the same throughout the life of each individual **object**, but 5 of which change. So i need, for each **object** to save it's previous states and go back to them.

**The question:**

> How do I apply the **Memento Pattern** with these objects?

**My idea so far:**

So **Memento Pattern** has 3 classes, **Memento** of which you create many, one for each state. **Caretaker** which stores all the previous states of an object AKA **Mementos**. And then the **Originator** that creates **Mementos** and also gets the states from a **Memento**.

This would mean that each **object instance** would require it's own **Caretaker instance** (a list of it's previous states), and this **Caretaker** would have **Mementos** with the previous states of this object's 5 attributes (and also the current state or only previous ones?), but all objects with a caretaker can use the same **Originator instance** because the **Originator** can be used to create new mementos into any **Caretaker**.

Is this how it would be implemented or am I misunderstanding it?

It would look something like this:

> Originator and Memento class

```
public class Memento {
   private Object1Attributes state;

   public Memento(Object1Attributes state){
      this.state = state;
   }

   public Object1Attributes getState(){
      return state;
   }    
}


static class Originator {
   private Object1Attributes state;

   public Memento saveStateToMemento(){
      return new Memento(state);
   }

   public void getStateFromMemento(Memento Memento){
      state = Memento.getState();
   }

   public void setState(Object1Attributes state){
      this.state = state;
   }

   public Object1Attributes getState(){
      return state;
   }

}
```

> Other object

```
public class Object1Attributes{
    string attribute1;
    int attribute2;
    someObject attribute3;
    someObject attribute4;
    someObject attribute5;
}

public class Object1 {

    CareTaker careTaker = new CareTaker();

    Object1Attributes;

    string attribute6;
    int attribute7;
    someObject attribute8;
    someObject attribute9;
    someObject attribute10;


    public void returnToPreviousState(){
        if(caretaker.Length()>0){
            Object1Attributes = originator.getStateFromMemento(careTaker.get(caretaker.Length()-1));
            caretaker.remove(caretaker.Length()-1);
        }
   }

    public void newState(ObjectAttributes OA){
        originator.setState(OA);
        this.ObjectAttributes = OA;
        this.caretaker.add(originator.saveStateToMemento());

    }

}
```

> Another option

would be making the Memento class and the Originator class hold the 5 attributes, instead of encapsulating the 5 attributes inside another class. Like so:

```
public class Originator {
    string attribute1;
    int attribute2;
    someObject attribute3;
    someObject attribute4;
    someObject attribute5;

   public Memento saveStateToMemento(){
      return new Memento(attribute1, attribute2, attribute3, attribute4, attribute5);
   }

   public void setAttribute1(string state){
      this.attribute1 = state;
   }

   public void setAttribute2(int state){
      this.attribute2 = state;
   }

}
```

This way each Object1 instance would hold its own instance of Originator instead of Object1Attributes though, and this Originator would contain the current state of the attributes in the object1 instance; I don't know which way is the correct way of implementing the pattern.

All examples online use mementos to store a "state" which is just a string, none of them involve the creation of multiple objects that can have multiple states, so that's why I'm so unsure.

Answer (score 1):

One of the common pitfalls when implementing the Memento pattern is exposing the  Originator's internal state. This breaks one of the fundamental OO-concepts called encapsulation.

The Memento has a state which captures the Originator's state. This can be an external type. You can also declare the needed properties in the Memento itself.  Later you can use the Mediator's state to revert back the Originator to that state.

```
class Memento {
    var state: State
}
```

The Originator shall have two Memento-related methods:

```
class Originator {
    func createMemento() -> Memento {
        let currentState = State(...)
        return Memento(state: currentState)
    }

    func apply(memento: Memento) {
        let restoreState = memento.state
        //...set the properties you want to restore from the memento state
    }
}
```

Finally, the Caretaker:

```
final class Caretaker {
    private lazy var mementos = [String: Memento]()

    func saveState(originator: Originator, identifier: String) {
        let snapshot: GameWorldMemento = originator.createMemento()
        snapshots[identifier] = snapshot
    }

    func restoreState(originator: Originator, identifier: String) {
        if let snapshot = snapshots[identifier] {
            originator.apply(memento: snapshot)
        }
    }
}
```

And this is how to use it:

```
let caretaker = CareTaker()
let originator = Originator()

// Save initial state
caretaker.saveState(originator: originator, identifier: "save0")

// modify the originator
// ...
// reset the originator to its original state
caretaker.restoreState(originator: originator, identifier: "save0")
```

This is just a simplified example to illustrate the concept.

Normally, I'd start by defining the three protocols. **Since the concrete "originators" are usually already existing types, I'd add a type extension to make it adopt the Originator protocol.** This way I don't have to modify its code. Actually, this way I can enhance types without modifying their original code.

Hope this helps.